# Unable to output array in general loop

Tags: php

I created some variables and tried to output them in a loop.
Displays all variables except array ($d)

**How to output this array($d) to the general loop along with other variables?**

```
$a = 1;        
$b = 1.2;      
$c = "xopa";   
$d = [32];     
$e = true;     
$f = null;     
 
foreach([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f] as $items){  // general loop, here, in theory, $d should be displayed
echo $items. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You can't echo an array, you'd have to var_dump() or print_r() it. (Or iterate over it and display each element.)

Comment: `$d` is an array so can't be echoed directly, it has no default visual representation. Before echoing `$items`, check if it's an array or not. If not, echo it. If it is, loop it and echo each item within it - just like you're doing with the outer array.

Comment: The loop does not influence the output in any way. Try `echo($d)` or `echo([32])` to see. An array cannot be displayed using `echo`. The arguments of [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo) must be strings. They are converted to strings if they are of other types. Read how the values of various types are [converted to strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

Comment: When using `print_r([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f]);` you should note that the variable names (`$a` -- `$f`) are gone too. Maybe you can print the values but not the names of the original variablenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for my first answer I misread and didn't take a look at the variable values. $d is an array so you need to check if the item is an array before echo using `is_array()`

```php
$a = 1;
$b = 1.2;
$c = "xopa";
$d = [32];
$e = true;
$f = null;

foreach([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f] as $items) {
  if ( is_array($items) ) {
    foreach ( $items as $child ):
      echo $child ."<br>";
    endforeach;
  } else {
  echo $items . "<br>";
  }
}
```

You could also pass the array through a function and loop though multiple arrays so you don't overload your code with multiple loops.

```php
function show_array_values($arr) {
  foreach($arr as $items) {
    if ( is_array($items) ) {
      show_array_values($items);
    } else {
    echo $items . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

show_array_values([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f]);
```

Comment: does not work =(

Comment: `Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type ???? in ...`  multiple times (with different types on the question marks.)

Comment: Yes I noticed I misread the question after I posted it’s because $d is an array. I will edit my answer

Comment: @Jamie Sayers, thanks, how many years have you been learning php?

Comment: @Icetime no worries, I've known php for around 12 years

Comment: @Jamie Sayers, trying to figure out how many years I need to reach your level =)

Comment: @Jamie Sayers, this is great code